# Meaning of "value of the frame property is undefined and should not be modified"?

Tags: ios, uiview

So in the `UIView` documentation you have:

> However, if the transform property contains a non-identity transform,
>   the value of the frame property is undefined and should not be
>   modified. In that case, you can reposition the view using the center
>   property and adjust the size using the bounds property instead.

So obviously after a transform is applied, I should not change the value of the `frame` to reposition or resize it, but are the values in `frame` still valid and make sense? i.e. can I still use them for calculations?

In a `UIImageView` which I applied a transform to, the value in `bounds` doesn't change at all and seems to reflect the size of the `UIImageView`
before it was transformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is pretty clear -

> the value of the frame property is **undefined**

So, you cannot rely on the frame property to have a sensible value if a non-identity transform is installed.

Comment: But when I check the frame of my image view after the transform, it has correct values for the height and width. The bounds still has the old non transformed values. Is that how it should be?

Comment: The `bounds` values are in the object's own coordinate space.  The object itself is unaware of the transformation, so the bounds values won't change.